# Power BI - link a merged column to an unmerged column from different tables within a chart

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to chart the combination of two columns along a single axis. For example, the combination of `Company A` and `Country 1`. The workaround I've done for this is to merge the two into a single column and pull in the data along that row.

Now, I want to add tooltips to the chart that take in aggregated data for just the `Company` from another table. Is there a way to do this, please?

A simple version of the two tables is below. The first contains aggregated data at the `Company` level. The second contains data broken down by `Company` and `Country`.

| Company | Aggregated 1 | Aggregated 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | 6 | 7 |
| Company B | 4 | 4 |
| Company C | 6 | 5 |

| Company | Country | Company-Country | Metric 1 | Metric 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | Country 1 | Company A-Country 1 | 7 | 7 |
| Company A | Country 2 | Company A-Country 2 | 8 | 6 |
| Company B | Country 2 | Company B-Country 2 | 6 | 5 |
| Company C | Country 3 | Company C-Country 3 | 8 | 9 |

Please note the data values aren't important and aren't meant to add up.

Comment: Bottom table is the one used in the chart? Which chart/visual type are you using? You should normally be able to add {Company] and [Country] into the same visual well to create a hierarchy in the visual which you can then drill on (ie no need for merged column). Is there a relationship between these two tables if not then create a relationship between the two on the `[Company]` columns, and then it should work.

Comment: Bottom table used for the chart, yes. It's a clustered bar chart, each bar being a metric score for a [Company]-[Country] combination. Ideally, the axis would merge the two columns implicitly without having to do it manually in the table itself. I've tried adding both columns to the same (y-)axis in the viz pane but it only shows one. There's a relationship between the two tables based on [Company].

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean by the hierarchy within the chart. That'll do, I'll work from there. Thank you very much for getting back to me.